# How save resultset in an ArrayList saving different row in the same cell?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arraylist, resultset

```
pstpr = con.prepareStatement("select id_prodotto from prodotto_autore where id_autore='" + id.getInt(1) + "';");
            prodotti = pstpr.executeQuery();
            while (prodotti.next()) {
                pstcoa = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id_autore FROM prodotto_autore  WHERE id_prodotto='" + prodotti.getString(1) + "';");
                coautori = pstcoa.executeQuery();
                List<String> row =null;
                while (coautori.next()) {
                     row = new ArrayList<>(); // new list per row
                     row.add(coautori.getString(1));

                    //prodott.add(coalizione.getString(2));
                }
                coaliz.add(row);
            }
```

where from the results of the first resultset i can compute the results of the second resultset. Now i want to save this results in an arraylist but in the same cell. I mean what i have is

```
[[2], [79], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
```

but what i need is instead

```
[[2, 79], [2], [2], [2, 2, 2]]
```

How can i do? thank you

Comment: I don't even understand what you actually want to achieve. Is it a list containing other lists? Why are 2 and 79 as well as the last 2's grouped and not the rest? And the most important question: _what did you try_?

Comment: from the first result set i obtain all the works that i have in the database then i compute for each work its authors that i want to store in one cell of the array, so i have 4 works and the authors id for the fisrt are 2 and 79 for the second 2 and so on..

Comment: You should parameterize these queries.  Your second query is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Hint: rename `row` to `cell` and you should see at least one flaw (as has already been stated in an answer): you're recreating the "row" list for every new author and since you're only adding `row` to `coaliz` after the loop you'd get only one element in `row`. - Besides that: debug your code and you should see where exactly it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    pstpr = con.prepareStatement("select id_prodotto from prodotto_autore where id_autore='" + id.getInt(1) + "';");
        prodotti = pstpr.executeQuery();
        while (prodotti.next()) {
            pstcoa = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id_autore FROM prodotto_autore  WHERE id_prodotto='" + prodotti.getString(1) + "';");
            coautori = pstcoa.executeQuery();
            List<String> row =null;
            row = new ArrayList<>();
            while (coautori.next()) {
                  // new list per row
                 row.add(coautori.getString(1));

                //prodott.add(coalizione.getString(2));
            }
            coaliz.add(row);
        }
```

You are trying to create a new array list inside the second result set. Instead create it outside the second result set and within the first result set.

Comment: Thank you indeed!! i'm sorry if i was not clear and i want also to thank who format my question